# How to get login status into variable

Tags: angular, facebook-login, angular2-services

I have login with facebook on in my angular service (`LoginService`)

```
login() {

    this.fb.login()
        .then((response: LoginResponse) => this.logResponse = response)
        .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
}
```

I want to monitor `logResponse` variable and as soon as it changes it should be examined if the user is connected, which I try to realise in different ways. The last one uses `ngOnChanges`

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (this.logResponse.status === 'connected') {
        this.isConnected(true);
    } else {
        this.isConnected(false);
    }
}
```

but I'm unable to change the value of `connectionOn` which is responsible for connection status. I have following variables in my service:

```
private connectionOn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);    
connectionOn$ = this.connectionOn.asObservable();
@Input() logResponse: LoginResponse;
```

`connectionOn` is observable which is responsible for toggling Login/Logout button in login.component.ts, there is getter and setter of `connectionOn` but it don't work in my service.

So, main question is how to toggle `connectionOn` whenever `logResponse.status` is changed.

My actual code:
[login.component.ts](https://pastebin.com/gMmxu5Ep),
[login.service.ts](https://pastebin.com/G2uSJYyt)

Comment: after getting the response, you should be getting the body of the http response using .json(). I would do .then((response: LoginResponse) => this.logResponse = response.json())

Comment: It shows warning that property json() doesn't exist on type LoginResponse. But the problem is how to get the actual value of `ogResponse` and if necessary toggle the `connectionOn` immediately. Thanks @ashley

Comment: It should be res that should be a type of Response not the other way round. Can you please try that? .then((res: Response) => this.logResponse = res.json())

Comment: It throws another bunch of errors, but actually the response is not a problem because I am able to get it. The problem is when it arrives, how to check if it has changed immediately after it come(the most important), and how to store it in the observable which will be responsible for toggling the Login/Logout button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understood correctly create a service class that will be used to notify subscribers about the new value

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class ConnNotificationService {

    private subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(true);
    constructor() {
    }

    sendMessage(message: boolean) {
        this.subject.next(message); //all subscribers get the new value
    }

    getMessage() {
        return this.subject.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then if you want to toggle, you can do as follows:

```
toggleConn() {
    if (this.logResponse.status === 'connected') {
      this.ConnNotificationService.sendMessage(true);
    } else {
      this.ConnNotificationService.sendMessage(false);
    }
```

For instance in your login.component or other components, you can get the value as follows

```
    import { ConnNotificationService} from '...';
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
...
    })
    export class LoginPage {
      connStatus: boolean;

      constructor(private connService: ConnNotificationService) {
        this.connService.getMessage().subscribe(val => this.connStatus=val);
      }
```

Hope that helps.

Ashley

Comment: Thanks very much for this repose, your hope come true ;)

Comment: if that works, grateful if you can mark my answer as the solution. thx.